# VB6 ListBox cannot reach bottom of content

Tags: forms, scroll, listbox, vb6

I am tasked with upkeeping an ancient VB6 project, and right now, I am plagued with an issue where a listbox cannot be scrolled (if that's even a word) to the bottom of the content;

[image: screenshot of listbox]

My apologies for the size, I cannot display any of the information in the application.

For the life of me, none of the properties seem to alleviate this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `IntegralHeight` to `True` in the design-time properties of the ListBox? This [prevents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263883(v=vs.60).aspx) this ListBox from displaying partial rows.